# R no longer runs or installs after upgrading Ubuntu to 22.04

Tags: shared-library

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 and now when I try to run R or re-install it, I get the following:

```
"home/markleeds/bin/R-4.2.0/bin/exec/R: error while loading shared libraries: libicuuc.so.67: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory."
```

I looked around quite a bit and found similar messages from other people but I haven't been able to locate a solution. It definitely has something to do with me upgrading Ubuntu because everything was working fine when I was using 21.10. Thanks for your help.

Comment: See which package provides it: `dpkg -S libicuuc.so`.

Comment: @waltinator: Thanks. When I run that command, I get the following 3 files:                                                     libicu70:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.70  and                                                 
libicu70:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.70.1 and
libicu-dev:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so

Comment: Does that mean that I need to change a path somewhere so that it looks for 70 rather than 67 ? Thanks and apologies for my ignorance.

Comment: What happened was that R was being built using libiuuc.so.67 ( because that's what I built it against before I upgraded Ubuntu ) and installed trying to use libiuuc.70. So, once I deleted the R directory completely, then  the shell script I use built AND installed against 70 and everything worked perfectly. Thanks to waltinator because his command led me to think that 70 was somehow being used and was incompatible with 67.

Comment: Feel free to add this answer to your own question: it then can help other users, and it is perfectly fine here to answer your own question.

Comment: okay. will do. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Vanadium's suggestion, I'm taking my comment and putting as an answer here.

What happened was that R was being built using libiuuc.so.67 ( because that's what I built it against before I upgraded Ubuntu ) and installed trying to use libiuuc.70. So, once I deleted the R directory completely, then the shell script I use built AND installed against 70 and everything worked perfectly. Thanks to waltinator because his command led me to think that 70 was somehow being used and was incompatible with 67.